# Union of two arrays of objects with properties that must be unique - ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two activerecord models:

```
 class M1< ActiveRecord::Base

 end

 class M2< ActiveRecord::Base

 end
```

They both have the same structure, they have `name` and `date` and `info` attributes.
I created 2 queries:

```
m1s = M1.where(...)
m2s = M2.where(...)
```

Now I want to union them one way or another.

So I do it simple:

```
m_all=m1s + m2s
```

So I got an array of objects:

```
    [#<M1:0x007fffdcc14100
      date: Fri, 15 Sep 2017,
      name: "name1",
      info: "blablablabla">,

     #<M2:0x007fffdd492e08
      date: Fri, 15 Sep 2017,
      name: "name2",
      info: "blabla"> ...
   ]
```

And now from this array, I need to select objects, where 
`(date, name)` - combination of date and name properties is unique. In other words, I don't need repeated objects, that have the same `date` and the same `name`

For example if I have 3 records:

```
 date="11.04.15" name="xxx" info =""
  date="11.04.15" name="yyy" info =""
  date="11.04.15" name="yyy" info = ""
```

It should select only the first two of them because second and third have the same date and name.

So what do I do?
I tried to do it like this but didn't work:

```
m_all= m_all.uniq do |m|
   [m[:date], m[:name]]
end
```

Comment: that should've worked.  What error or result did you get?

Comment: @user2950593 All you should need to do is put m_all = m_all.uniq if I'm understanding your objective correctly?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn the result is the same array before and after with the same number of elements

Answer (score 1):

I tried it on a sample database where I am, and the `uniq` code worked fine. Are you absolutely sure that `date` is a date field?  If it's a datetime field you may be finding the matching fails for that.

Try this to only match on year month day (I would also suggest `to_date` but I've occasionally had issues with that)

```
m_all= m_all.uniq do |m|
   [m[:date].to_datetime.strftime('%Y%m%d'), m[:name]]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you need to use [pluck](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck):

Eg:

```
m1s = M1.where(...).pluck(:date, :name, :info)
m2s = M2.where(...).pluck(:date, :name, :info)

m_all = (m1s + m2s).uniq
```

**Sample O/P**

```
[["11.04.15", "xxx", ""], ["11.04.15", "yyy", ""]]
```

**NOTE:** I tried to suggest it in comments but, since it's unreadable there, I posted it as answer.

**EDIT**

If you need the info with keys, the use [select](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/select)

```
m1s = M1.where(...).select(:date, :name, :info).as_json
m2s = M2.where(...).select(:date, :name, :info).as_json

m_all = (m1s + m2s).uniq
```

**Sample O/P**

```
[{date: "11.04.15", name: "xxx", info: ""},
 {date: "11.04.15", name: "yyy", info: ""}]
```